# R package for fixed length vectors

Tags: r, vctrs

I'd like to have fixed length/dimensions vectors/matrices in R. Pseudocode:

```
foo <- fixed_character(LETTERS, length = 26)
foo <- LETTERS[1:10] # throws an error, wrong length

bar <- fixed_matrix(NA, 6, 2)
bar <- matrix(1:12, 3, 4) # wrong dimensions
```

This would be useful for catching errors and writing robust code. Are there any packages on CRAN that do this?

Comment: Use Rcpp? It's a core feature of the R language that vector length is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I recalled that the [rtype](https://github.com/renkun-ken/rtype) system allows you to check the dimensions of vectors and data frames on assignment. The [vctrs](https://cran.r-project.org/package=vctrs) package also seems relevant.